# discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this discord bot made in python, and I am starting using the cogs. I followed the instructions of the documentation. However, it does not appear to be working, may I be missing something? I even watched some videos regarding that, however, I am unable to load the cog correctly.

This is the Cog code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


class Greetings(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        channel = member.guild.system_channel
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}.')

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
        """Says hello"""
        member = member or ctx.author
        if self._last_member is None or self._last_member.id != member.id:
            await ctx.send(f'Hello {member.name}~')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'Hello {member.name}... This feels familiar.')
        self._last_member = member

async def setup():
    await bot.add_cog(Greetings(bot))
```

And this is the main.py file function that loads the cogs

```
#Load cogs
async def load():
    for file in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]}')
```

I am facing this error: `discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found` As I said, this is the same code snippet from the official discord.py documentation https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html

I tried re-writing the hello command, changing the way it loads the cogs into the file. I expect the output of the if-else block. But it is throwing this error

**Edit: This is not greeting new members either... Seems like the cogs are not being loaded into the main.py file.**

**Edit: Problem solved, I forgot to define the main function that will call the load() and start the bot**

Main function

```
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load()
        await bot.start(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the bot param in your setup function.

```py
async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(Greetings(bot))
```

Also, don't forget to call `load()` function in your main file to load all extensions.

Comment: When doing that I still get the same error as well as this one when calling the load() function `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'load' was never awaited
  load()`

**Edit: Still not greeting the new members**

Comment: @paxanoA1607 where do you call `load()` and did you add `await` keyword since `load()` is an async function? It is better to call `load()` inside your main async function for starting the bot

Comment: This is how I am calling the load() function  `load()` just before the `bot.run(token)`

Comment: @paxanoA1607 so you call load by `await` (inside async function) or get the event loop to call it in sync function? Because your error above shows you does not correctly call the async function `load`

Comment: Still, the error wasn't solved by that. I've been trying to load the cogs for about a week now (not programing all days) and I am starting to piss off, any suggestion to load the cogs?

Comment: Hey, I solved the issue, it was my bad, I forgot to define and call the main() function

Comment: Great. Never thought that will be an issue tbh

Comment: Same, it seemed a bit weird though